# If EPR has better resolving power than NMR, why don't most MRI machines use EPR instead of NMR?

Tags: mri, bone-scan

Most MRI machines use NMR imaging instead of EPR imaging even if EPR could provide a better image with more information. What could be the reason of this preference of technique?

[image: image showing the resolution of EPR is better than NMR]

Comment: I have a strong suspicion this is an engineering question that few, if any, medical professionals could answer.

Comment: From what little I understand, EPR imaging is different to MRI http://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae359.cfm It would be like asking why X-ray machines don't use a different form of radiation.